# casting BindList<Classname> to BindingList<Interface>

Tags: c#, casting, bindinglist

I have an object (class A) that implements an interface I.

My object C has a BindingList listA

At one point I need to perform the following cast:

```
BindingList<I> funcName(){
   ...
   return (BindingList<I>) C.listA;
}
```

But this does not compile because of a cast error.

How should I go and do that?

Comment: it's a BindingList<A>. I'll correct it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) issue. It's been addressed in .NET 4.0 but not for all enumerable types, and I don't think it's been addressed for BindingList<T>.

I think your only option is to create a new instance of BindingList as follows:

```
BindingList<I> funcName(){
   ...
   return new BindingList<I>(C.listA);
}
```

Alternately, you could declare your C.listA field as a BindingList<I> and just add instances of your class to it.

Comment: +1. .NET 4 introduces covariance and contravariance on interfaces and delegates, but not on classes.

Comment: +1 These are the only solutions I can see as well. Note: BindingList<I> only takes a constructor of type IList<I>, so I think you mean: return new BindingList<I>(C.listA.OfType<I>().ToList()); (or similar)

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the link that's very interesting. However, BindingList<I> won't accept anything else in its constructor other than an IList<I>.

Comment: Well you're right. I was able to solve this by changing part of the architecture. Hopefully this will be addressed in future versions of .net. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for the help.